# Speed up for loop with if in r

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I have a dataframe called dataSessions, where I have 3 columns "Timestamp","CookieID","Name", with over 1,3 million rows. It has been ordered according to CookieID and Timestamp.

I want to create a new column called "Sessions", which displays 1 or 0 according to some criteria.

The criteria for 1 is:

```
1) The previous cookie is not the same as the current
2) The time between the same cookieID is over 30 minutes
```

I have tried to do a code where a for if loop runs each row and checks if the CookieID has been there before. But this procedure takes a loooong time. 
Is there a quicker and more efficient way to do this?

```
dataSessions$Test<-lag(dataSessions$CookieID, n = 1)

for (i in 1:length(dataSessions$CookieID)) {
  if(dataSessions$CookieID[i] %in% dataSessions$Test[i]) {
    dataSessions$New[i] <- 0
  } else {
    dataSessions$New[i] <- 1
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the data, and the SESSIONS column I want generated:

```
Timestamp              CookieID     Name     SESSIONS
2015-08-28 15:46:03    223284       A        1
2015-09-19 22:26:50    223223       A        1
2015-09-19 22:27:09    223223       A        0
2015-09-19 22:28:11    223223       A        0
2015-09-20 22:29:14    245458       B        1
2015-09-20 22:30:17    245458       B        0
2015-09-20 23:05:01    245458       B        1
2015-09-20 23:06:15    245458       B        0
```

As is shown, Sessions are only 1 when beginning a new CookieID, or when a CookieIDs last entry is more than 30 minutes old.

Comment: I don't get how your code work, on my system it return 0 for each (maybe a version problem ?). A `dput(head(dataSessions))` could be of help to reproduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a faster way to do this with `data.table`, but in the meantime:

```
dd <- read.csv(header=TRUE,
stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="
Timestamp,CookieID,Name,SESSIONS
2015-08-28 15:46:03,223284,A,1
2015-09-19 22:26:50,223223,A,1
2015-09-19 22:27:09,223223,A,0
2015-09-19 22:28:11,223223,A,0
2015-09-20 22:29:14,245458,B,1
2015-09-20 22:30:17,245458,B,0
2015-09-20 23:05:01,245458,B,1
2015-09-2023:06:15,245458,B,0")

dd$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(dd$Timestamp)
```

Find time diff (in seconds, converted to half-hours) - set time between first observation and "previous" to infinite:

```
dt <- c(Inf,diff(dd$Timestamp)/(60*30))
```

Find cookie diff:

```
dcookie <- c(NA,diff(dd$CookieID))
```

Check either case:

```
dd$SESSIONS <- as.numeric(dcookie!=0 | dt >1)
```

The logic here is that we are looking for cases where

- `dcookie!=0`: the difference between the previous and current (numeric) cookie values is not zero (i.e., cookie has changed)
- `dt>1`: the difference between the previous and current time stamp is > 1 half-hour

In a context where we could do efficient looping (almost any language but R, e.g. Python or using C++ code via `Rcpp`) we would want to first check for equality of cookies (faster than subtraction), then *if* cookies were equal do the time difference calculation - that would shave off a bit of time.

Comment: This is great, easy and VERY fast. Much appreciated

Can you please explain a bit more about what happens in the last code with Sessions?

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` alternative to the answer of @BenBolker is:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, session := +(Timestamp - shift(Timestamp, 1L, "lag") > 1800 | 
                           CookieID != shift(CookieID, 1L, "lag"))
          ][1, session:=1]
```

this gives:

```
> df
             Timestamp CookieID Name session
1: 2015-08-28 15:46:03   223284    A       1
2: 2015-09-19 22:26:50   223223    A       1
3: 2015-09-19 22:27:09   223223    A       0
4: 2015-09-19 22:28:11   223223    A       0
5: 2015-09-20 22:29:14   245458    B       1
6: 2015-09-20 22:30:17   245458    B       0
7: 2015-09-20 23:05:01   245458    B       1
8: 2015-09-20 23:06:15   245458    B       0
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1440769563, 1442694410, 1442694429, 1442694491, 1442780954, 1442781017, 1442783101, 1442783175), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CookieID = c(223284L, 223223L, 223223L, 223223L, 245458L, 245458L, 245458L, 245458L), Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = ("Timestamp", "CookieID", "Name"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```